# filtering only previously unselected <select> options qith JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Previously I asked how to do this and was directed to this:

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.filterByText = function(textbox) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var select = this;
        var options = [];
        $(select).find('option').each(function() {
                    options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
        });
        $(select).data('options', options);

        $(textbox).bind('change keyup', function() {
            var options = $(select).empty().scrollTop(0).data('options');
            var search = $.trim($(this).val());
            var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");

            $.each(options, function(i) {
                var option = options[i];
                if(option.text.match(regex) !== null) {
                    $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

(http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/)

When I use this filter on the select box it filters both the unselected AND the selected. I'd like it to ONLY filter the unselected because if a user wants to ammend the selections and filters again, the previously selected items go away - unless they meet the filter criteria.

I'm not that good at JavaScript or JQuery and can't understand how I might tell the above script to ignore options that are ":selected" but filter all else.

Here's a jfiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/UmKXy/ I'd like option one and two to remain selected and in the list when user begins to type.

Thanks for help!

Comment: you should provide a jsfiddle maybe

Answer (score 0):

to selected the non selected options, use this:

```
$('option:not[selected]')  or  $('#myselect > option:not[selected]')
```

to remove them, use this:

```
$('option:not[selected]').remove();
```

in css, `:not` filters for opposite of what comes in the curved brackets.
and `[]`  is attribute selector.

so `:not[selected]`  means:  `does not have an attribute whose key is "selected"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution you had would not work with selected elements because he created an array of options at the start and then matched those options against the regex(Without regards to what is actually selected). I've used spans to hide options in the past and created an example for you to see how it works. Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/rD6wv/

Here is the code

```
$(function() {
  $("#filterByText").bind('keyup',function(){
    var search = $.trim($(this).val());
    var regex = new RegExp(search,"gi");
    $("#filez").find('option').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).is(':selected')){
        if($(this).val().match(regex) === null) {
          $(this).wrap('<span>');
        }else if($(this).parent().is('span')){     
          $(this).parent().replaceWith($(this));
        }
      }
    });     
  });
});
```

You simply need to loop through all the options of the select when you type in the textbox.
You then check if it is selected, if it is you do nothing, else you check if it matches the search filter, if it does you wrap it in a span, making it invisible, else it means you need to see it, so you check if it is already wrapped in a span, and in that case you replace it with the option so you can see it again.

Comment: This seems a little kludgy - I don't want to wrap any of the items with spans to make them disappear, I want an unselected option in the list to become "<option...selected> when selected and a previously selected option to become "<option...>" when selected.

Comment: I don't understand, did you not want a list that can be filtered, but the selected items are not affected by the filter? I also don't see what "kludgy" is, wrapping options in span works on all browsers and is simple.